# how to use .gif files in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting a problem in displaying the .gif file in my view.Actually I am getting the .gif files from the parser and I need to display the into my view.Can anyone suggest how to use the .gif file in our app.I am struggling a lot for this.Can we convert .gif,.tiff and .jpg files into .png with progrmming?

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank to all who helped me,
Monish.

Comment: "I am getting a problem in displaying the .gif file in my view." If you want people to be able to answer, specify what problems you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImage already support gif file. So you should be able to show it in UIImageView. What is the problem that you are getting actually? There might be some other problem. Please post some code so that we can further check.

For testing you can use a png and check whether the problem is actually causing by gif or not.

Comment: Just a note: UIImage will only display the first frame of the gif, but not animate it.

Comment: Yes thats true. But in this case I assumed there is only one frame, as he was trying to convert it to a png :-)

Comment: @Satyam svv, as far as I know only first frame of GIF is shown in UIImageView, at least with older SDK. Not sure whether this is improved in latest SDK.

Comment: Even with newer SDK its not possible. We've to write some decoder class to get each and every frame, and then animate it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found is to use this perfect UIImage Category
https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif/